# "es kommt zu etwas"-meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence:

> Heute Abend **kommt es** immer wieder **zu** teils kräftigen Schauern.

This "es kommt zu etwas", is it just a fixed phrase tantamount to "es gibt"?

Comment: it should be possible to look this up in a dictionary

Comment: @Alazon A short survey shows: It's hard or impossible to find in Duden, dict.cc, leo.org, en.wiktionary. Only in DWDS (meaning 8) it is easier to find. And a monolinguistic dictionary is not easy to use for a beginner. If only dictionaries would sort their meanings by valency...

Comment: I see. DWDS are the best :)

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, "es kommt zu etwas" is a fixed phrase with a similar meaning to "es gibt" or "es findet statt". It is often used for things that happen without anybody (directly) causing them or having control over them, like the rain in your example. You may say that the rain showers *happen*.

It may be noteworthy that there are very similar phrases that can have seperate meanings:

> Ich bin heute endlich dazu gekommen, den Keller aufzuräumen.
> Today, I finally got around to clean up the basement.

> Wie konntest Du es dazu kommen lassen!
> How could you let it come to this!

> Sie waren arm, aber vor kurzem sind sie zu Geld gekommen.
> They were poor, but recently they've come into money.